# Associating a block to a method after defining it

Tags: ruby, methods, dynamic

This is much more a curiosity than something I am living in a real situation.

Let's assume I need to define a method at a certain point of my program, using

```
self.class.send(:define_method, method_name)
```

without a block.

It happens that at this point I still don't know exactly what this method must do. In other words, I don't have a block of code to associate with this method.

My question is: **Is there some way to create this association afterwards? A way to say 'Hey, from now on this method shall execute this block here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just redefine it with

```
self.class.send(:define_method, method_name, &block)
```

Methods can be redefined as many times as you want.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't considered this possibility.